draw the angle of perpendicular distance between point and a line
i tray with this coordinates, the point is R=(x0,y0),the line is AB where A=(x1,y1) and B=(x2,y2), but i didn't know if it is really perpendicular, and i can't draw the angle projection.
R = (2, 6) 
A = (8, 4)  
B = (2 ,1.8)

How can I choose the coordinates to get the perpendicular?

There is no question here. I don't see a connection with Python. Seems like this is a question on mathematics.

i edit it, i can't choose the right coordinates to get a perpendicular angle projection

Possible duplicate of Perpendicular on a line from a given point

Write the (parameterised) equation of the straight line as
x=x1+t(x2-x1), y=y1+t(y2-y1)

Write the (squared) distance of point (x0,y0) from this line:
R^2=(x1+t(x2-x1)-x0)^2+(y1+t(y2-y1))^2

Differentiate R^2 with respect to t to find the minimum. (Line of code below).
Use this value of t to get the projection point. Note that if t lies outside [0,1] then the projection point is outside the line segment.
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0, y0 = 2, 6

x1, y1 = 8, 4
x2, y2 = 2, 1.8

t = -( (x2-x1)*(x1-x0)+(y2-y1)*(y1-y0) ) / ( (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 )
p, q = x1 + t * ( x2 - x1 ), y1 + t * ( y2 - y1 )

print( "Projection point is ", p, q )
print( "Nearest distance (to extended line) is ", math.sqrt( ( p - x0 ) ** 2 + ( q - y0 ) ** 2 ) )

plt.plot( [x0,x1,x2], [y0,y1,y2], 'o' )
plt.plot( [x1,x2], [y1,y2], '-' )
plt.plot( [x0,p ], [y0,q ], '--' )
plt.show()

Output:
Projection point is  3.357492654260529 2.2977473065621936
Nearest distance (to extended line) is  3.9432805267237567



how can i draw the angle projection in pythton please?

What do you mean by "angle projection"? The projection is indicated by the dashed line.

the angle projection between the point and the line, a right-angle symbol
